# window.location.reload(true) sends get request

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, window.location

I am developing MVC Web application.
I use HttpPost via form.submit to request all views except first/default view.
Therefore url in browser's address bar does not change i.e. stays `http://mymachine:62846`
When I try window.location.reload(true) url becomes `http://mymachine:62846/Home/GetPartialView` and web browser displays error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. Requested URL: /Home/GetPartialView

in `HomeController` Method `GetPartialView` is marked `HttpPost`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetPartialView(BroadcastedData data)
```

Based on aforementioned error my understanding is when `window.location.reload(true)` is executed browser sends `HttpGet` request or `HttpPost` w/o post data and server can't route request properly.

Am I wrong?

How can I reload page via code properly essentially mimicking user pressing CTRL + R?
Thank you.

Comment: why do you want to reload the page?

Comment: I am changing themes (using devexpress controls) in order to apply theme I need to reload page

Answer (score 0):

As your action method is of type `[HttpPost]` it needs post data. I hope there is a `[HttpGet]` action method through which your view is rendered. You have to set the URL of the particular action method(`[HttpGet]`)to window.location rather than reloading the page .

```
 window.location = url;
```

And for doing this on ctrl+R, try the following code:

```
$( document ).bind( 'keydown', function ( event )
                {
                    if ( event.which == 82 )//R=>82
                    {
                        if ( event.altKey )
                        {
                            window.location=desired_URL;
                        }
                    }
                } );
```

Comment: There is no HttpGet method, views are rendered via HttpPost. Why needs to be get method? Browser can reload page sending post data, got to be a way to do the same in code.

Comment: If that is the case, why don't you just submit the form again?

Comment: because the form content's (e.g. inputs) do not have the same values... it is dynamic app, each view is generated based on previous navigation/user selection, thus each view generates recreates the form w/ its own content...

Comment: What do you mean by each form have different values? Then how can you use the same action method for posting?

Comment: `public ActionResult GetPartialView(BroadcastedData data)` here the post method accepts data from a view that is strongly typed( model: BroadcastedData ). Isn't it?

Comment: Each view changes values of input fields before broadcasting... Re>" strongly typed" you are correct, so?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28876/discussion-between-slacker-and-alexander-gurevich)

Comment: You mean only the values of the input fields are changing? Then I am repeating y dont u just submit the form again and generate the view in the mathod based on some condition. ? Sorry if I misinterpreted your comment